# Magically changing timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, date, urlencode

I have a date string `"20 November, 2013"` and a time string `"9:30 AM"`

I need to get certain info from this string.

```
$date = "20 November, 2013";
$time = "9:30 AM";
$str = $date." ".$time;
$dtime = strtotime($date);
$DAY = date("d",$dtime);
$MONTH = date("m",$dtime);
$ttime = strtotime($time);
$HOUR = date("h",$ttime);
$MIN = date("i",$ttime);
$MER = date("A", $ttime);
```

I'm trying to get `$DAY` to == "20", `$MONTH` to == "11", et cetera. When the values are hard-coded in like above, seems to work fine, but when I replace `$date` and `$time` with my `$_GET` parameters it breaks and returns incorrect data.

The script is being called from ajax.

```
var param11 = document.getElementById('dpdate').value;
var param1 = encodeURIComponent(param11);
var param21 = document.getElementById('dptime').value;
var param2 = encodeURIComponent(param21);
var url = "https://www.nnnn.com/picker/timeajax.php?time="+param1+"&date="+param2;
xmlhttpp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttpp.send(null);
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Or a way to fix what I'm currently doin?

Comment: And what's the exact input you get from directly var_dump()'ing your $_GET parameters?

Comment: the script is called from ajax. i'm not sure how i could var dump it as i'm not entirely sure how to alert the url javascript var. i tried but the code sort of just skips that part for some reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Moment Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323032/javascript-moment-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.
I used it couple of times and was really happy with the results.