# Javascript Moment Library

Tags: javascript, php, date, time, momentjs

I am currently using ajax to execute the following php code which deconstructs a date/time string.

```
//date string
$date = "20 November, 2013";

//time string
$time = "9:30 AM";

// get timestamp for date
$dtime = strtotime($date);

//get day of month - 20
$DAY = date("d",$dtime);

//get month - 11
$MONTH = date("m",$dtime);

//get timestamp for time
$ttime = strtotime($time);

//get hour - 09
$HOUR = date("h",$ttime);

//get min - 30
$MIN = date("i",$ttime);

//get meranda - AM
$MER = date("A", $ttime);
```

How can I get these same values using the JS [Moment library](http://momentjs.com/) from any string in the above format?

Comment: Ummm... What did you try?

Comment: `goto google_for_docs;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not very clear, but consider:

```
moment("20 November, 2013, 9:30 AM UTC").format()
```

returns (in my TZ):

```
"2013-11-20T10:30:00+01:00"
```

or, you can obtain date parts from the `moment` object like this:

```
date = moment("20 November, 2013, 9:30 AM");
hour = date.hour()
```

etc, see [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/).